# Restricted access using .htaccess in Docker container

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, access-control

I'm literally at the end of my knowledge. I've set-up a few server and sometimes I've used .htaccess for restricted access.

It's always working except for my latest work. I have an Debian instance running inside of a Docker container with Apache2.

Adding a .htpasswd-File work's fine. Except that the part in my .htaccess doesn't work.

/var/www/.htaccess exists
/var/www/.htpasswd exists

code inside my .htaccess:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Members Only"
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

There exists a file `_index.html` I can access this file using https://sub.domain.com/_index.html. That's why I know that /var/www is my entry point for accessing my website.

Comment: What do you mean part of your `.htaccess` doesn't work? I'm assuming you have more in your `.htaccess` than what you've posted.

Comment: yes, I do have some custom Rewrite (historical reason) after this part.
Hm, Do you think that my .htaccess isn't used?

Comment: and you're sure that `/var/www/.htpasswd` is the correct path? Go directly to the file and check the properties of the file. Find out the exact path.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I have to Allow Override for this directory.